# How to attach the text to the parent in SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I created a demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzLEQX
But I want that the text was inside the container g id = "g12" but how to do this? Do I need the variables x = y =?

```
  <g id="g12">
    <title>Header 12</title>
    <desc>Text 12</desc>
      <path id="path16" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#231f20;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 482.25,470.173 H 260.693 V 607.898 H 482.25 Z" />
    <text x="30" y="90"  fill="#ED6E46" font-size="100" font-family="'Leckerli One', cursive">Watermelon</text>
  </g>
```

Comment: You codepen link is broken or maybe it's my browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SVG, the `<g>` element represents just a logical/descriptive grouping.  It doesn't imply any physical grouping.  An element won't shift on the page, just because it is inside a `<g>` tag.  It's not like HTML where text inside a `<div>` will respond to the position and size of the `<div>`.

In SVG, if you want to physically move an element around, you have to position it yourself by changing its coordinate values.  In the case of `<text>`, that normally means changing its `x` and `y` values.  However, you can also adjust the position of an element with the `transform` attribute.

So, to answer your question: yes, you need to change the `x` and `y`.